# How can I migrate my flutter coded and firebase hosted app to a no-code platform?

Tags: flutter, firebase, data-migration

I have an app built with flutter and hosted on firebase. It is a marketplace app with buyer and seller. The development was outsourced. Now I want to re-build the app with no-code platform. However, there are already many users registered and seller posted their products on my marketplace, I want to have a smooth transition without having all my users to register and post products again. So I guess I need a no-code platform that can integrate my existing firebase database and settings? What are the suggested no-code platform that can perform such transition?

I've been searching for no-code tools online such as Bubble, Sharetribe and Thunkable. But I want seek advice from the professionals here.

Many thanks all!

Comment: I use to build apps through flutter flow and it's pretty easy to work with. You can simply connect your firebase to it so you can access all data and can show there easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [Flutterflow](https://flutterflow.io/) which is a no-code platform for Flutter without any code. You can integrate Firebase using Flutterflow so the transition could be quite easy too.

If you don't want such a big hassle, maybe try learning Flutter if you have the time? It's not a bad idea since Flutter is pretty easy.

PS: You've said you want the platform to *do* the transition. Flutterflow won't exactly *do* the transition for you, I hope you didn't mean it like that. You'll have to do it yourself but it's quite easy.

Comment: Will have a try on Flutterflow. Thanks a lot!